# rspec The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`

Tags: ruby, rspec, matcher

using the new expect syntax:

```
 expect(@line.filter_results_and_display_them).to == @processed
```

Getting this error:

> ArgumentError: The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to '#to'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This syntax works:

```
expect(@line.filter_results_and_display_them).to eq @processed
```